# Named query to join 2 tables from another table

Tags: hibernate, hql, named-query

I am working on a Java EE project using hibernate, I am facing a class diagram similar to this one:

[image: my Classes]

What I want to get is a list of customers who ordered a product. That means my named query has to get ID of the wanted product, and I want my named query to be writing on Customer class.

Can you help me in this one please?

Those are my classes :

```
@Entity
@Named Queries({
    /* NAMED QUERY THAT I M LOOKING FOR */
            })
public class customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_CUSTOMER", nullable = false)
    private Integer idCustomer;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 255)
    private String name;    

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 255)
    private String email;    

    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ORDER", referencedColumnName = "ID_ORDER", nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private GroupeAccess idOrder;  
}

@Entity
public class order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_ORDER", nullable = false)
    private Integer idOrder;

    private Date date;    

    @JoinTable(name = "order_product", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ORDER", referencedColumnName = "ID_ORDER", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PRODUCT", referencedColumnName = "ID_PRODUCT", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<product> productCollection;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idCustomer")
    private Collection<customer> customerCollection;
}

@Entity
public class product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_PRODUCT", nullable = false)
    private Integer idProduct;

    private Date date;    

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productCollection")
    private Collection<Acces> orderCollection;
}
```

Comment: i want to select customers for all orders of a products , not only one order

Answer (score 1):

`Select o.customerCollection from Order o where :product in o.productCollection`

Comment: in terms of optimization , if i have like 10000 products , this query will work fast?

Comment: The underlying SQL will be like select c.* from customer c inner join order o on c.id_order = o.id inner join order_product op on o.id = op.id_order where op.id_product = ?. That is three table join. With correct indexes it should be fast enough.

Comment: mmm what i get here is customers of "one" order of a product ; what if i want list of customers of all orders of a product  ?

Comment: Can you execute the SQL query I provided in previous comment directly on DB?

Comment: the query u gave me will give me a collection of collection of customers right?